# How to infuse black layer of peppercorn into an oil?

Tags: oil, pepper

I am interested in infusing the black layer flavours(not inner white parts) of black pepper into an oil.

1. I imagine this can be achieved by adding whole black peppercorns to oil and frying a little. Or do you have to add whole black peppercorns to oil then leave it overnight?
2. If you say you need to grind the peppercorns first, why so? Since I am interested in the black part only would putting it be whole be better it is there some reason flavour would not extract so well like this?

Comment: you may need to clarify why only the black part of the peppercorn.

Comment: The black parts taste very different to the white and I am only interested in that.

Comment: Clearly, white pepper has a flavor that is different from black.  But, have you tasted only the black outer layer?  How do you know it is the flavor you are looking for? How do you know that the black pepper flavor is only coming from the outer layer, and not from the entire peppercorn?  For some infusion tips: https://www.bonappetit.com/test-kitchen/how-to/article/diy-flavored-oil

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on an oil, it can be done by taking black peppercorns, infusing them in high-grade alcohol for a couple of weeks at room temperature and then evaporating 90% of the alcohol and infuse the last 10% of the alcohol into the oil.

The easy way would be to infuse them in the cheapest <s>moon shine</s> vodka you can lay your hands on for 3 months and then using the vodka $instead of oil.*

If you insist on only the outer part, you can use an electric potato grater to peel off the outer skin only and infuse the "black powder" **:-)** in a neutral oil like grapeseed oil heated to below its smoke point for as long as possible.